# Can i admit only 2 numbers in readline?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I only want 0 or 1... if i write 2 or more I want the program to throw an exception ... how can i only accept this 2 numbers?

```
 while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BET OR PASS? (BET == 0 / PASS == 1)");
                int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                return n;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid Ans!! try again");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see why your program would crash specifically if you write 2 or more. Debug your program and find where it's crashing. What exception are you getting? Where? You should `break` out of the loop when you get an acceptable answer.

Comment: It will crash at {int.Parse} if the input is not a valid number.

Comment: @IsmailHawayel - 2 is a number. :-)

Comment: it is but the keyboard has too many funny chars that can break the parsing ? :)

Comment: reworded with what I think the OP means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use exceptions for control flow. Rewrite using `TryParse`:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BET OR PASS? (BET == 0 / PASS == 1)");
    int n;
    bool isOk = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);
    if(isOk && n >= 0 && n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid Ans!! try again");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want only `0` or `1` read only one char:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey(false); // this read one key without displaying it

if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.D0)
{
    return 0;
}

if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
{
    return 1;
}

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid Ans!! try again");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
```

Take a look at [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the try you can just throw like this;

```
try
{
     Console.WriteLine("BET OR PASS? (BET == 0 / PASS == 1)");
     int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if (n != 0 || n != 1)
         throw new InvalidArgumentException();
     return n;
}
```

basically, read the input no matter what, check it afterwards. If it's not a 1 or a 0 then you throw and invalid argument exception. That will actually be caught by your catch block but what you want to do once you recognize the error is up to you. If you really want the program to crash like you say then remove the catch and your program will crash anytime and exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true)
{

         Console.WriteLine("BET OR PASS? (BET == 0 / PASS == 1)");
         int n;
         if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
         {
            n = -1;
         } 

         if(n == 0 || n == 1)
         { 
            return n;
         }
         else
         {
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
             Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid Ans!! try again");
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
         }
}
```